# How to force ssl on login page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, devise

In `config/environments/production.rb` I have set:

```
config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::PasswordsController.force_ssl }
```

However, when I visit the page of new login, I expected to have https forced, but that does not happen.

I have checked `controller_path` in the login view page, it was `devise/session`
Any idea?

Comment: Try this. In your `production.rb`, set the `config.force_ssl` to `true`. It's easy to miss since it's commented by default but usually it's around line 42 and 43.

Comment: But wouldn't this force HTTPS on all routes?

Comment: Yes. But why wouldn't you want all your routes in https?

Comment: I get notification rest calls from other services to my web site that I am not sure they will work with https

Comment: Oh I see. Too bad I can't help you with this one :)

Comment: No problem, I think I have to test those rest notifications with https